# Bash - Moving files from subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell

I am relatively new to bash scripting.

I need to create a script that will loop through a series of directories, go into subdirectories with a certain name, and then move their file contents into a common folder for all of the files.

My code so far is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#used to gather usable pdb files
mkdir -p usable_pdbFiles
#loop through directories in "pdb" folder
for pdbDirectory in */
do
    #go into usable_* directory
    for innerDirectory in usable_*/
    do
        if [ -d "$innerDirectory" ] ; then
            for file in *.ent
            do

            mv $file ../../usable_pdbFiles

            done < $file
        fi
    done < $innerDirectory
done
exit 0
```

Currently I get

```
    usable_Gather.sh: line 7: $innerDirectory: ambiguous redirect
```

when I try and run the script.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `< $innerDirectory` and `< $file` redirections if you don't know what they do.

Comment: there are multiple errors here but without more details on the directory tree I can't help you. The error is due to `< $innerDirectory`. There is no need to do this, remove it. Same goes for `< $file`

Comment: Removing the two < statements worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirections `< $innerDirectory` and `< $file` are invalid and this is causing the problem. You don't need to use a loop for this, you can instead rely on the shell's filename expansion and use `mv` directly:

```
mkdir -p usable_pdbFiles
mv */usable_*/*.ent usable_pdbFiles
```

Bear in mind that this solution, and the loop based one that you are working on, will overwrite files with the same name in the destination directory.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for this answer! I'm still learning all the ins and outs of bash, so this kind of was an "ah-ha" piece of code for me.